# Custom PyCharm docstring stubs (i.e. for google docstring or numpydoc formats)

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

Does PyCharm 2.7 (or will PyCharm 3) have support for custom docstring and doctest stubs?  If so, how does one go about writing this specific type of custom extension?

My current project has standardized on using the Google Python Style Guide (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html).  I love PyCharm's docstring support, but it's only two supported formats right now are epytext and reStructureText.  I want, and am willing to write myself, a PyCharm plugin that creates a documentation comment stub formatted in either Google or Numpydoc style (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-napoleon/). Of special importance here is incorporating the type inference abilities that PyCharm has with the other two documentation types.

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9795.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

With PyCharm 5.0 we finally got to select [Google and NumPy Style Python Docstrings](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/python-integrated-tools.html) templates.

It is also mentioned in the [whatsnew](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/) section for PyCharm 5.0.

How to change the Docstring Format:

> File --> Settings --> Tools --> Python Integrated Tools

There you can choose from the available Docstrings formats:

> Plain, Epytext, reStructuredText, NumPy, Google

As pointed out by jstol: for Mac users, this is under

> PyCharm -> Preferences -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools.

Comment: For Mac users, this is under PyCharm -> Preferences -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools.

Comment: Any idea how to make this selection stick when I start a new project? It's a pain to have to hunt down this setting every time.

Comment: Consider updating this answer to include info in comment from jstol

Answer (score 4):

As CrazyCoder mentions, its a [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9795). Right now, you can only use `EpyType` and `reStructuredText`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be make @Nras answer explicit, as of [PyCharm 5.0](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/python-integrated-tools.html):

> File > Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Docstrings  >
>   Google