# Empty docstring inserted in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

Lets say I have the code:

```
def blabla(num):
```

When I am doing triple "", I should receive:

```
def blabla(num):
    """
    param: num
    return:
    """
```

But I get:

```
def blabla(num):
    """
    
    """
```

Which means basically nothing, A week ago it was all good.
Searched sphinx style and others, nothing I changed at Pycharm helped.
Asked my teacher and he did not know how to fix it, told me to ask SOF ( This forum ).

Edit: I have tried going to Editor >> General >> Smart keys.
But all are V in there... no other solution for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing up"? What exactly was good a week ago? I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @mzjn Hi, by not showing up, as you can see, The expected ( first code ), the one I have is the second one. I dont see any parameters, return and such when I go docstring.
By the sphinx way.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very unclear. "when I go docstring. By the sphinx way" - what does that mean?

Comment: @mzjn Oh, the documention I wrote above at the post, is called sphinx documentation. but it doesnt matter. My point is, I should get a pattern docstring automatic when I am doing """""" , but I do not get anything. only what you see in the second code.

Comment: So this is a problem with how PyCharm behaves then?

Comment: @mzjn Exactly. I think.

Comment: https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html
Look here, I should receive like here.

Comment: Have you configured [this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497841) in the integrated tools? Without it PyCharm doesn't know what docstring style to generate. After typing the quotes twice `""` PyCharm should expand them to six `""""""` with the caret in the middle, if you press `Enter` there the docstring stub is inserted.